# Spring NoHandler found despite warning pointing correctly to the JSP that should handle my view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, web.xml

My web.xml is the following ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="Your_Webapp_ID" version="3.0">


    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>MyMVCAppCustom</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyMVCAppCustom</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.app</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The warning I am getting is .....

```
WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DynWebProj/WEB-INF/springMVCjsps/MyHello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'MyMVCAppCustom'
```

The really strange thing is that SPRING has gone into my controller method and has gone to my view resolver and it is clear that my jsp file is at this location **/DynWebProj/WEB-INF/springMVCjsps/MyHello.jsp** but yet it claims that there is no handler there !!! I even get a system.out message posted from my Controller class.

```
printHello3 {message=hello Hello Spring MVC Framework!}
```

In the tomcat console it all loads well as well ....

```
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/bingo],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String code.xander.mvc.MyHelloController.printHello3(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)
INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'MyMVCAppCustom': initialization completed in 1931 ms
```

My browser url is .....

```
http://localhost:8080/DynWebProj/bingo.app
```

I am really flummoxed and at my wit's end because I have been struggling with this for 3 days on the trot. The odd thing is that it suddenly started working and now it has stopped. What gets me is the almost quantum behavior of this issue.

If you have reached reading here I might as well add my controller class in as well ...

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class MyHelloController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/bingo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String printHello3(ModelMap model) {
          model.addAttribute("message", "hello Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
          System.out.println("printHello3 " + model);
          return "MyHello";
       }
}
```

Added my Spring mvc servlet config xml file over here .....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

   <mvc:annotation-driven />
   <context:component-scan base-package="code.xander.mvc" />


   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/springMVCjsps/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

As you can see even though Spring+Tomcat does not render my page. The warning maps exactly to where my jsp page is ..... so, I just cannot understand why it cannot render it.

`WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DynWebProj/WEB-INF/springMVCjsps/MyHello.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'MyMVCAppCustom'`

DynWebProj is my web root for my application. I used eclipse. I get the same msg when I "runas" and when I create a WAR file and deploy to my tomcat webapps directory.

Comment: show us how you configured ViewResolver bean in spring bean or complete configuration file.

Comment: @Rembo have added my spring config file

Comment: add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` & `<context:annotation-config/>`  and try.